# Finding Observation Index in a `zoo` object

Tags: r, zoo

I am loading data into R and I would like to find the observation number associated with a certain date. Is there function/ command that can allow me to find the observation number for date "2010-09-24", which is 7 in the data? How about the observation number for the maximum weight in the sample? In the data example it would be 53348 at observation 5. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
    library(zoo)    
    dat=read.zoo("filelocation",header=T,colClasses=c("Date","numeric"))

 obs     date   weight
  1   2010-10-04 52495    
  2   2010-10-01 53000    
  3   2010-09-30 52916    
  4   2010-09-29 52785    
  5   2010-09-28 53348    
  6   2010-09-27 52885    
  7   2010-09-24 52174    
  8   2010-09-23 51461    
  9   2010-09-22 51286    
  10  2010-09-21 50968    
  11  2010-09-20 49250
```

The structure of the data is so:

```
>dput(head(data))
structure(c(100, 101.01, 110.75, 111.24, 104.96, 104.95, 104.06, 
109.08, 113.48, 111.6, 108, 107.95, 95.96, 100.5, 109.05, 103.57, 
103.88, 104.66, 100.34, 108.31, 109.4, 104.87, 106, 107.91, 22351900, 
11428600, 9137200, 7631300, 4598900, 3551000, 100.34, 108.31, 
109.4, 104.87, 106, 107.91, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 6:7, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("weight", "height", "BMI", "Age", "Age2", "Intr", 
    "Chol")), index = structure(c(12649, 12650, 12653, 12654, 
12655, 12656), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

Comment: Type this, and edit the question to include the output: `dput(head(dat))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zoo class is composed of two structures, the index and the core. You want to query one column of the `coredata`. Of necessity that is a character matrix, since you have character values in it. So with that in mind:

```
 which( coredata(dat)[ ,2] == "2010-09-24")
```

(You cannot have Date classed variables in a zoo core which is a matrix. You should probably learn how to read the data so the Date column is used as the index column.)

```
 dat=zoo(read.table(text="obs     date   weight
  1   2010-10-04 52495    
  2   2010-10-01 53000    
  3   2010-09-30 52916    
  4   2010-09-29 52785    
  5   2010-09-28 53348    
  6   2010-09-27 52885    
  7   2010-09-24 52174    
  8   2010-09-23 51461    
  9   2010-09-22 51286    
  10  2010-09-21 50968    
  11  2010-09-20 49250",header=T))

> which( coredata(dat)[ ,2] == "2010-09-24")
[1] 7
```

## After Question Edited

The only date value in that object is in the index rather than the core:

```
which(index(dat) == as.Date("2004-08-24")) 
#[1] 4
```

This illustrates using `which.max` (on the coredata but you do not need to access with the `coredata` function since `[.zoo` will implicitly "assume" that is what you are interested in.)

```
> which.max(dat[,"weight"])
[1] 4

> dat[ which.max(dat[,"weight"]) , ]
           weight height    BMI    Age    Age2   Intr Chol
2004-08-24 111.24  111.6 103.57 104.87 7631300 104.87   NA
```

Comment: Hi DWin, thank you for the help. So far the command has been giving me  this as output: integer(0). What should I do?

Comment: I was unable to create a zoo object that looked exactly like yours. With mine I get the answer `7`. You should follow the advice of Lundberg and post the output of `dput(dat)`.

Comment: When you say "You cannot have Date classed variables in a zoo core which is a matrix" are you alluding to the fact when timeseries data, with a date variable, is pulled into R, using the zoo package, that the date variable is no longer in the datastructure? Because I notice that my date header acan never be referenced in the data and is called "row.names" when I type View(dat)

Comment: The matrix class does not allow elements to be 'dates' unless they have been coerced to 'character'. Ordinary R Dates have a class attribute that controls how they get printed but they are in fact integers.

Comment: @Dwin maybe, to complete the answer you can add `which.max` for the second question about the maximum weight in the sample?

Comment: DWin. Thank you so much it worked. If I understand your correctly, zoo converts the dates into numbers/integers benchmarked from some starting time and the index() command coerces the integer dates back to characters, such that they can meet the as.Date() requirement.

Comment: @gabriel no. see `class(index(dat))` is Date , So you coerce "2004-08-24" to Date, to meet zoo requirement.

Comment: got it! thank you so much agstudy and DWin. Big hugs to you two!

Comment: @DWin +1 great answer as usual! your are every where here! I learn a lot from you and some guys here!

Answer (score -3):

You could try to use:

```
which(data == 'foo')
```

and that should return the index value. You could use the following example to show this -- the format seems to have been jumbled by copying/pasting into SO, but 'cars' is the dataset.

```
which(cars$dist == 2)    
[1] 1
```